# Add static content to a disabled option on a select input

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using a component which renders select inputs. I need to add a label because I cannot handle the HTML it renders to freely add a label I need.

Here is the HTML generated by the library I'm using

[image: select html]

My problem is that there is no label shown such as "Select an option" or "Choose one" or something like that.

[image: no label]

Any idea of how can I solve this?

The library's documentation does not provide me a solution.

Comment: What library do you use?

Comment: Presumably, you're working with a component, since this is react... at minimum it'd be useful to know which component.

Comment: add your component and tell what labrary you're using

Comment: The library is React awesome-query-builder